# Hadoop: Permission denied error while running a python script through streaming jar package

Tags: python, hadoop, permission-denied

[The error message image, the task is run through hadoop user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVKq4.jpg)

I am running a hadoop job in python executables, all the files have been given all permissions i.e. read, write and execute and is owned by hduser.

It gives me an error saying permission denied.

[ls -ltr /home/hduser/majorProject screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UfwN.jpg)

I ran another example before, and it runs perfectly

I have 5 files mapper.py reducer.py hidden.py oauth.py twurl.py

When i run the python scripts through terminal, they run fine meaning the scripts themselves are ok. Need help desperately, there are no threads that are helping in the situation online.

Comment: can you `ls -ltr` in `/home/hduser/majorProject`. Consider setting it 777 `chmod 777 *` for all files in that folder.

Comment: added the screenshot requested.

Comment: why not try after `cd /home/hduser/majorProject` then from there you need not to specify path every time. Not sure if this will help but no harm in trying

Comment: From the error screenshot, it seems it is searching for `mapper.py` in a wrong location. Instead of `/home/hduser/majorProject/mapper.py`, file is being looked up under `/home/hduser/./mapper.py`. Check the scripts for any wrong relative referencing.

Comment: The scripts show the correct paths, though i think the Linux might be putting in the /./mapper.py as a stand-in because of less print area in terminal?